# Communication between device for 5 meters and low speeds

Tags: communication, cables, rs485, slew-rate

I need to make a communication between only two devices with a distance of 5 meters, which are connected by a cable of 4x2.5mm² (see in the image), being 1 wire for GND and wire for 12v, that would pass nominal current lower than 10A, and the other two wires will be for communication.
I thought to use rs485, would it be possible to use 4 way cable without being twisted for a 5 meter distance and slow speed rate (1 byte every 50ms at most)? Would you have any other suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

[image: cable]

Comment: Although rs485 is better for long distance, 5 meters it not *that* a long distance. You can easily do standard RS232 over 5 meters. The drivers for that are a bit easier to obtain. I don't now what you are trying to do but how about a run-of-the-mill USB cable with RSR232 at the end? It also has power (but not 10A) and signalling.

Comment: It depends how noisy the 10A is on what needs to be done.

Comment: Check out the LIN bus (you can run your normal UART using LIN transceivers, you don't have to follow the LIN protocol itself). Should do fine in this scenario.

Comment: Unidirectional or bidirectional?

Comment: If each receiver has 1 millisecond low pass filter to remove most noise (100 ohms, 10uF ceramic), or a 160Hz LPF, with hysteresis such as 74LS14 or modern equivalent, this datalink may be simple. Depends on the ground-currents and the ground-spikes between the 2 systems. That may upset the bits.

Comment: @oldfart I can not use usb cable, and accurate it provides 10A without significant loss of voltage, so wire needs to be at least 2.5mm² and environment that personal not to be careful, so that cable.Even so will have chance of short on the cable, and then would need ic to have protection against short, those of rs485 have.
@ sunnyskyguy-ee75 This cable will power a circuit for control of DC motors, but I will add 2200uf capacitor and with cable inductance, there should be so much noise.

Comment: filo => I really liked it, I'm researching more and soon in the beginning find out that it is for automotive system, which is my system. It will be used to control a low cost agricultural implement.

cl => is biredicional.

@analogsystemsrf It is an automotive environment (inexpensive agricultural implement), can have short on the cables, the reception tinho imagined with comparator used hysteresis, the problem would be transmission, as it may be short and do not want to have high resistance at the output, as it will pick up very noisy.

Comment: Thanks to all who are helping me, I will analyze all the suggestions. My English is kinda bad, so sorry if any of it gets kinda hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The TIA-485 standard does not specify what kind of cable you have to use for RS-485 networks. Twisted pair is very frequently used because it's cheap and works very well for most scenarios.

For your particular application I would say it depends on how noisy your power supply and loads are but at such a low speed unless you have to deal with a horribly noisy environment you should be good.

I would like at it from a different angle though: you're wasting quite a lot of copper there. But I guess 5 meters is not that long, but you might consider replacing your four-wire with a two-wire for power plus a twisted pair that would be probably cheaper and lighter.

If you are asking for a theoretical development of this problem a very good reference is this one: *Noise Reduction Techniques in Electronic Systems* by H.W. Ott. In there you will find the how and why of the twisted pair.

Another good reference to look at is: *Serial Port Complete* by J. Axelson. This book will give you a lot of tips on the practical side of RS485.